# standard Brownian motion 3

Tags: probability, expectation, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

How one can prove $$\mathbb{E}[W_{t}^{2k}]=\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}t^k,$$

where $\{W_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion on some filtered probability space $(\Omega , \mathcal{F}_{t}, \{\mathcal{F}_{t}\}_{t\ge 0}, \mathbb{P})$ and $k$ is a positive integer?

I know that it is possible by using induction and Ito formula. Here I want to prove based on standard results. I mean using normally distributed function and moment function. Thanks!

Comment: For a fixed $t$, $W_t$ is just a normal random variable with mean zero and variance $t$. Do you know how to find the moments of a normal random variable?

Comment: @carmichael561 Moment formula :$M^{(k)}(0)=E(X^k)=k!f(k)$. But,  I couldn't  go further

Comment: I think we get use Ito's formula to get that isn't it? but I did see the above lint has used that formula. @ armichael561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $t>0$, $W_t$ is a normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $t$, and has pdf
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}} $$
Using this pdf and completing the square, one can show that the moment generating function for $W_t$ is
$$ M(s)=\mathbb{E}[e^{sW_t}]=\exp\Big(\frac{ts^2}{2}\Big) $$
On the other hand,
$$ M(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbb{E}[W_t^k]}{k!}s^k $$
so by comparing coefficients it follows that $\mathbb{E}[W_t^k]=0$ if $k$ is odd, while
$$ \mathbb{E}[W_t^{2k}]=\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}t^k $$